# Importing script files into ASP.NET page: intellisense shows the methods, but trying to call one errors. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I put a function in an existing.js file (I tried two different files) so that the method would be available multiple places without repeating the code. I even created a simple function just to make sure it wasn't something my function was messing up.

```
function doNothing() {
    alert("Dammit."); 
}
```

I can see the method in the intellisense list in my .ascx control, but as soon as I try to step into it, it fails.

Below is how I tried to reference the file and it seemed to work as far as seeing the methods, but it won't work.

```
<script src="/javascript/messages.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any ideas? Any common mistakes that I may be making? It looks like it should work.

Note: when the methods are inside the .ascx file, they work fine, even with missing semi-colons.

Comment: It could be that the file isn't being loaded correctly because of a virtual directory or some other path issue.  change src="/javascript/messages.js" to src="~/javascript/messages.js" if this is webforms.  Try @Url.Content("~/javascript/messages.js") for MVC.

Comment: You can also use the debugging tools of most browsers to determine if the file is being loaded properly.

Comment: It should be, I used the browse that pops up when setting the src attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if IntelliSense suggested `"/javascript/messages.js"`, the path will be wrong if your application is installed under a virtual directory instead of at the root of the Web site. For example, the full URL of the JavaScript file might be at http://www.example.com/myapp/javascript/messages.js, but because the `src` attribute starts with a `/`, the browser will access http://www.example.com/javascript/messages.js (without the "myapp" virtual directory) instead.

If you're using WebForms, you can change the `src` attribute as follows:

```
src='<%= this.Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/javascript/messages.js") %>'
```

Comment: Nice! My.WebNewbiness -= 1; That was it. I thought about posting the lyrics to 'Wind Beneath My Wings' for you, but thought it may get awkward...Thanks!